# Using Sparksql to union two columns with null value in either of them

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I'm trying to use SparkSQL to process a dataframe.The dataframe looks like:

```
    A    B
    1    Null
    2    Null
   Null  3
   Null  4
```

How can I use join or union to form a new column `C` so that the dataframe can be:

```
    A    B      c
    1    Null   1
    2    Null   2
   Null  3      3
   Null  4      4
```

*It's guaranteed that A and B will not both be null or non-null; either of them will have a value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `coalesce` function; According to the [docs](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.sql.functions$):

> It returns the first column that is not null, or null if all inputs are
>   null.
>
> For example, coalesce(a, b, c) will return a if a is not null, or b if
>   a is null and b is not null, or c if both a and b are null but c is
>   not null.

```
val df = Seq((Some(1), null), (Some(2), null), (null, Some(3)), (null, Some(4))).toDF("A", "B")
// df: org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame = [A: int, B: int]

df.withColumn("C", coalesce($"A", $"B")).show
+----+----+---+
|   A|   B|  C|
+----+----+---+
|   1|null|  1|
|   2|null|  2|
|null|   3|  3|
|null|   4|  4|
+----+----+---+
```